# Не назначается стиль через PHPExel

Tags: php, excel

Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой, при работе с `phpExel`.
Суть: не вешается стиль для правой границы ячейки.
При этом в тестовом скрипте всё работает. С другими границами проблем нет

Код в продакшен:

```
<?php

function cellStyle($css_class) {

    //парсим название класса
    preg_match_all("/border_(\w+)/", $css_class, $matches_border);
    $matches_border = $matches_border[1];

    //предопределяем стили для границ ячейки
    $boredr_style = array(
        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
        'color' => array('argb' => '000000')
    );

    //формируем массив стилей для границ
    $border = array(
//        'left' => in_array('left', $matches_border) ? $boredr_style : array(),
//        'right' => in_array('right', $matches_border) ? $boredr_style : array(),
//        'top' => in_array('top', $matches_border) ? $boredr_style : array(),
//        'bottom' => in_array('bottom', $matches_border) ? $boredr_style : array(),
        'allborders' => $boredr_style,
    );

    //возвращаем массив стилей
    return array(
        'borders' => $border,
    );
}

$pExcel = new PHPExcel();
$pExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$aSheet = $pExcel->getActiveSheet();
//Устанавливаем заголовок по названию потребителя
$title_xls = $title;
$aSheet->setTitle(iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $title_xls));
$aSheet->setCellValue($column . $line, iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $text));
$style = cellStyle($c['css']);
$aSheet->getStyle("A1")->applyFromArray($style);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл в чём проблема.
В коде активно используется объединение ячеек (о чём я раньше не сказал, каюсь).

```
$aSheet->mergeCells($column . $line . ":" . $lc . $line);
```

Стиль назначается только первой ячейке.

```
$aSheet->getStyle($column . $line)->applyFromArray($style);
```

Назначенный стиль относиться только к ячейке с координатами $column.$line, в то время, как правая граница по факту является частью другой ячейки(или так считали разработчики фреймворка) с координатами $lc.$line
Добавил код

```
$aSheet->getStyle($lc . $line)->applyFromArray($style);
```

...и всё заработало.